# Date of signing or date of signature

Tags: phrases

I don't now which variant is correct.

Some context. I have a paper document with signature. This document has a property — date when signature was created. My english teacher says that correct variant is "date of signing", but I found usages second variant in [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wye_River_Memorandum)

> The Memorandum determined that it would enter into force on 2 November 1998, ten days from the **date of signature**.

Can you say, variant "date of signature" is correct or not?

Comment: If I sign a document today and then date my signature tomorrow, the document will  not come into force until tomorrow because that is 'the date of signature'.

Comment: From a legal perspective, I've never read a case that implied that the language labeling a signature was important other than to the extent that the words implied some fact about the actual signing that might be relevant (e.g., board consents under Delaware law). (Other parts of the sentence are unidiomatic: "The Memo determined" and "it would enter into force" are not usual phrasings.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an idiom as far as I can research from searches on https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ or http://www.word-detective.com or with a Google search.

Both say the same thing. If you search the phrases in quotes in Google, you'll find that "date of signing" has more results, but not by a significant amount. Both variants work.

Answer (score 1):

I think since you are describing the date when an event took place the noun *signing* is more descriptive.

Use of the word signature is also correct.